# Does calling a function break recover()?

Tags: go

I was using a library which `recover()`s from panics, and it was using code that simplifies to the following:

```
func main() {
    defer rec()
    panic("X")
}

func rec() {
    rec2()
}

func rec2() {
    fmt.Printf("recovered: %v\n", recover())
}
```

The output of this is:

```
recovered: <nil>
panic: X
... more panic output ...
```

Notably, `recover()` returns `nil` instead of the error. Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recover` must be called directly by a deferred function.

from the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics):

> The return value of recover is nil if any of the following conditions
>   holds:
>
> - panic's argument was nil;
> - the goroutine is not panicking;
> - recover was not called directly by a deferred function.

Comment: Wasn't recover() called from a deferred function though (rec was deferred in main)? I believe you, I'm just not quite understanding :)

Comment: @william.taylor.09: No, the deferred function here is `rec`, and `rec` is only *directly* calling `rec2`; `rec2` is what calls `recover()`. Changing the defer to `rec2()` will catch the panic.